# The size of my images has changed even though I haven't made any changes to the code

Tags: java

Today i ran an amateur project i've been working on for a while. My problem is:
Everything looked bigger and the outlook didn't even fit on the screen.
Things I did differently than yesterday:

- I formatted my computer and installed windows 10 instead of windows 8.
- I installed the March 2021 version instead of the eclipse 2020 june version.
- I downloaded the latest version of jdk (16.0.1)

Can you help with what the problem is about?

Comment: @Michael I already told you that I didn't make changes to the code before the format. Do you still want the code?

Comment: @user15793316 oh, I dont remember previous JDK release. But i will try starting with changing the screen resolution

Comment: please try to use the same configuration you had it before installing new OS. it might be the issue of newer JDK version, but still cross check first.

Comment: @user15793316 Changing "eventual scale in Display Setting" worked, thanks. But at the moment other applications seem very small. Instead of changing this scale every time, is there an alternative solution I can use?

Comment: @PapaifromBEKOAIL The problem was with 'eventual scale in Display Setting ' but I am wondering: by configuration do you mean jdk version?

Comment: Even though you didn't change the code, the code is still relevant because the specific classes you're using may have changed between versions. If we knew what the code looked like, we might be able to say "class X changed in Java 9. It used to do Y, now it does Z"

Comment: @Michael yes that makes sense